# Problema con el IF en java

Tags: java, if

compañeros estuve empezando con una nueva clase y me sorprendio como el if no funciona con numeros enteros es decir no compara correctamente el mayor que y el menor que 
El codigo es el siguiente

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Conservacion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int c1,c2,c3,i1,i2,i3,vi,vc,total;
        Scanner lee=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(lee.hasNext()) {
            total=0;
            vc=0;
            vi=0;
            c1=lee.nextInt();
            c2=lee.nextInt();
            c3=lee.nextInt();
            i1=lee.nextInt();
            i2=lee.nextInt();
            i3=lee.nextInt();
            vc=(c1*c2*c3);
            vi=(i1*i2*i3);

            if(vc>vi) {
                total=vc/vi;
                System.out.println(total);
            }
            if(vi<vc) {
                System.out.println("0");
            }

        }
    }
```

Y esta es la salida

```
10 10 10 9 9 11

1

0
```

SI NOTAIS ME CORREN AMBOS IF ES DECIR NO FUNCIONA CORRECTAMENTE EL PRIMER IF SI SABEIS COMO SOLUCIONARLO LES DARIA LAS GRACIAS

Comment: Si `vc > vi` es verdadero entonces `vi < vc` también lo es. En el segundo `if` debería ser `vi > vc`.

Answer (score 1):

No hay ningun problema en el if, el problema es con la condicion. Si te fijas bien, estas invirtiendo el orden de las variables y al mismo tiempo el usas el operador inverso... osea que es basicamente la misma condicion.

`vc>vi` es lo mismo que `vi<vc`

Comment: GRACIAS NO ME HABI DADO CUENTA

Answer (score 0):

**//VC mayor que VI...**

```
if(vc>vi) {   
    total=vc/vi;
    System.out.println(total);
}
```

**//VI menor que VC(igual que en el if anterior solo que a la inversa)**

```
if(vi<vc) {
    System.out.println("0");
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
***//MI opinion..***

```
if( VC > VI ) {   
    total=vc/vi;
    System.out.println(total);
}else if( VC < VI ) {
    System.out.println("0");
}
```

//de esta forma o es un if o es el otro

```
si( vc MAYOR_que vi){código...}  (SI o NO)
entonces si(vc MENOR_que vi ){código..}
```

espero ser de ayuda en tu pequeña confusión, solo es al realizar la comparación...